# How to deal with special characters inside XML string attributes?

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

So I have some input from a web form that's sent as XML and goes through an XSS filter that canonicalises/unencodes all of the text before it hits the server. So on the client side we send:

`<term><var>x</var><while exp="x&lt;3"><dostuff></dostuff></while></term>`

Which turns into

`<term><var>x</var><while exp="x<3"><dostuff></dostuff></while></term>`

Then when I parse the xml, of course it breaks.

Do I have to step through every attribute and re-encode them, or is there an easy way to do this in groovy/grails?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever filter you're putting it through, it is corrupting your data, so get it fixed or scrap it quickly before it does irreparable harm.

In the general case, repairing your data isn't possible. If the filter putting unescaped angle brackets into your data stream, you might be able to detect some of the cases, but in the worst case it will be indistinguishable from genuine markup.

Comment: Isn't canonicalisation the standard way of preventing xss though? I believe we're using the ESAPI library. I suspect what people usually do is either cook up their own encoding scheme, or reprocess the data once it reaches the server using contextual knowledge.

Comment: I don't know the software that you are using, but the evidence from your post is that it is corrupting your XML. It might just be the way it's configured, I don't know, but you need to fix the problem at source rather than trying to repair the damage.

Comment: Fine and thanks for the answer. However if you're saying that a common XSS lib is corrupting data then you could back that up a little. What are alternative anti-XSS methods?

Comment: I'm only going on the information in your question. Something has corrupted your data and the only thing you have told us about is an "XSS filter".

Comment: Well it's ESAPI canonicalize. Like I say, it seems to be the standard way to prevent xss attacks.

Comment: I don't know the product, but a quick google shows that it supports a great variety of formats of which XML is just one. So my guess would be that it was run with the wrong configuration options.